# Extending User model in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I am trying to create a profile model for all of my users. I have the following code in which I get one custom field `birth_date`, but cannot seem to get any of my other custom fields to work:

forms.py:

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class SignUpForm(UserCreationForm):
    birth_date = forms.DateField(help_text='Required. Format: YYYY-MM-DD')

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'first_name','last_name', 'birth_date','location', 'password1', 'password2', )
```

models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    bio = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=True)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    birth_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_user_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.profile.save()
```

views.py

```
from django.contrib.auth import login, authenticate
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .forms import SignUpForm

def home(request):
    return HttpResponse('fd')


def signup(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SignUpForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save()
            user.refresh_from_db()  # load the profile instance created by the signal
            user.profile.birth_date = form.cleaned_data.get('birth_date')
            user.profile.college = form.cleaned_data.get('college')
            user.save()
            raw_password = form.cleaned_data.get('password1')
            user = authenticate(username=user.username, password=raw_password)
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('home')
    else:
        form = SignUpForm()
    return render(request, 'accounts/profile.html', {'form': form})
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [

    url(r'^register/$', views.signup, name='profile'),
    url(r'^home/$', views.home, name='home'),

]
```

If I were to remove `location`from forms.py, the form would load properly and allow me to fill it out and upon submission all data, including the custom field `birth_date` would save. But when I try to add `location` to the form, I get the following error:

```
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/forms/models.py", line 262, in __new__
    raise FieldError(message)
django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Unknown field(s) (location) specified for User
```

I am not sure why I cannot add the `location` field to the form.

Answer (score 0):

Because it's not a field on User. You need to do the same as you have for birth_date - declare it separately in the form class, and save it explicitly to the profile in the view.

Comment: I have been trying to get this to work for days, thank you!